# Angular2 Routing. Slash in the end of url

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have trouble with routing.

When I add in url 'myapp.com/route' one more slash in the end like that 'myapp.com/route/' my resources loading from 'myapp.com/route/...'.

For example: I had library that have to be loaded from 'myapp.com/starwars.js', but with slash it will be loaded from 'myapp.com/route/starwars.js'.
http://prntscr.com/9gpeen

But it is normal without slash 
http://prntscr.com/9gpepv

**Code**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Route, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router'
  import {NotFound} from './notfound/notfound';
import {TimerComponent} from './timer/timer.component'

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:`
      <a [routerLink]="['Timer']">Timer</a>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
  })
  @RouteConfig([

    { path: 'timer/', name: 'Timer', component: TimerComponent},
    new Route({path: '/**', component: NotFound})
  ])
  export class AppComponent { }
```

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do you include your `starwars.js` but it is probably relative to current url. That's why it is resolved to wrong address when you have a slash in your address.

You can try adding **base url** to your page:

```
<base href="/">
```

With this, you will ensure that, all relative addresses are going to be resolved against `/``.

For more information please see [Angular 2 doc here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#set-the-lt-base-href-).

Comment: this was the problem for me, my <base> tag was in the wrong place, whoops! thank you!